# What does n[::-1] means in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a string `n = "abc"`.

I want to reverse it and found a solution like `n[::-1]`.

What is the meaning of all 3 arguments?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Perhaps `reversed` is faster, but it returns an iterator, not a string.

Comment: Reopened.  This question asks specifically about the meaning of the slice notation which is different from the question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python .  That question is string specific and goal specific.  This question just about the syntax.

Answer (score 43):

It means, "start at the end; count down to the beginning, stepping backwards one step at a time."

The slice notation has three parts:  *start*, *stop*, *step*:

```
>>> 'abcdefghijklm'[2:10:3]  # start at 2, go upto 10, count by 3
'cfi'
>>> 'abcdefghijklm'[10:2:-1] # start at 10, go downto 2, count down by 1
'kjihgfed'
```

If the *start* and *stop* aren't specified, it means to go through the entire sequence:

```
>>> 'abcdefghijklm'[::3]  # beginning to end, counting by 3
'adgjm'
>>> 'abcdefghijklm'[::-3] # end to beginning, counting down by 3
'mjgda'
```

This is explained nicely in [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation), in the Python docs under "extended slicing", and in this blogpost: [Python Slice Examples: Start, Stop and Step](https://www.dotnetperls.com/slice-python)